# How I can use not selector in my tabs to show tooltip message on hover

Tags: html, css

I am making a page there are 3 tabs "seeker", "Owner" and "Admin".

1. If seeker logs in then "Owner" and "Admin" tabs should display tool-tip message "You are not authorized for this section/Tab" on hover of "Owner" and "Admin" tabs
2. and if Owner logs in then "Admin" tab should display tool-tip message "You are not authorized for this section/Tab" on hover of "Admin" tab.

Is this possible that we can achieve this using CSS :not() selectors? I tried but no luck. Or is there other way to achieve this?

here is my working:

https://codepen.io/shahzad80/pen/KYJexJ

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn tooltip right">
      <span>Seeker</span>
      <span class="tooltip-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    </a>
  </div>

<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn tooltip right">
      <span>Owner</span>
      <span class="tooltip-content">You are not authorised for this Section</span>
    </a>
  </div>

<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn tooltip right">
      <span>Admin</span>
      <span class="tooltip-content">You are not authorised for this Sectiont</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: you need to add a class if admin/owner login

Comment: As @Vel says; https://codepen.io/anon/pen/axXagx.
If 'Seeker' logged in. Same way need to work out other two people. 'login' is class used, expect that one person login.

Comment: add a class like if admin user login admin-login like ...

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot know who is logged in or not, so you have to use Javascript to add CSS classes depending on who is logged in. (Or you can load a different CSS file for different users, but that seems clunky)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn tooltip right">
      <span>Seeker</span>
      <span class="tooltip-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row.allowed a > .tooltip-content {
  display:none !important;
}
```

JS, the seeker is logged in so we allow the first button

```
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row")

// allow the first row
let seeker = rows[0]
seeker.classList.add("allowed")
```

You can allow the other rows by using `rows[1]` and `rows[2]`

You could turn this around and only add the `tooltip` class to rows that are not allowed, instead of hiding the tooltip when the button is allowed.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrZRQr)